# Errors show when I try to preview my app on my android devices

Tags: android, angular, typescript, nativescript, sidekick

I'm trying to create an app using Nativescript Sidekick using angular/typescript.

When I try and preview the app on my android devices it only shows the errors below.

I have tried running the preview several times on multiple android devices.

As soon as I make changes to the app.component.ts file the nativescript preview app begins showing the below list of errors

This snippet works

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "ns-app",
    templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

This snippet does not

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "gr-login",
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: "./login/login.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

> LOG from device Marvin: Angular is running in the development mode. Call >enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>   LOG from device Marvin: HMR: Checking for updates to the bundle with hmr >hash 4a9d4dd775f015fffecd.
>   LOG from device Marvin: Angular is running in the development mode. Call >enableProdMode() to enable the production mode. LOG from device
>   Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/app.module.ts LOG from device Marvin:
>   HMR: Successfully applied update with hmr hash 4a9d4dd775f015fffecd.
>   App is up to date. LOG from device Marvin: HMR:          ↻
>   ./app/app.component.ts LOG from device Marvin: HMR: The following
>   modules were updated: LOG from device Marvin: HMR: Checking for
>   updates to the bundle with hmr hash c892cbd39be51a20e8ba. LOG from
>   device Marvin: HMR: The following modules were updated: LOG from
>   device Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/app.component.ts LOG from device
>   Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/app.component.html LOG from device
>   Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/login/login.component.html LOG from
>   device Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/app.module.ts LOG from device
>   Marvin: HMR: Successfully applied update with hmr hash
>   c892cbd39be51a20e8ba. App is up to date. LOG from device Marvin:
>   Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to
>   enable the production mode. LOG from device Marvin: An uncaught
>   Exception occurred on "main" thread. Calling js method run failed
>   Error: Failed to create View with entry.create() function.
>        StackTrace:
>         Frame: function:'ZoneAwareError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 1298, column: 31
>         Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js',
>   line: 45, column: 13
>         Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 985, column: 32
>         Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.resetActivityContent',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 946, column: 10
>         Frame: function:'_resetRootView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js',
>   line: 125, column: 13
>         Frame: function:'NativeScriptPlatformRef._livesync', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js',
>   line: 268, column: 19
>         Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js',
>   line: 97, column: 80
>         Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invokeTask', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 421, column: 23
>         Frame: function:'Zone.runTask', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 188, column: 39
>         Frame: function:'ZoneTask.invokeTask', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 496, column: 28
>         Frame: function:'ZoneTask.invoke', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 485, column: 40
>         Frame: function:'timer', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 1561, column: 23
>         Frame: function:'invoke', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.js',
>   line: 19, column: 45
>         Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invoke', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 388, column: 18
>         Frame: function:'Zone.runGuarded', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 151, column: 39
>         Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 129, column: 23
>         Frame: function:'run', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.js',
>   line: 23, column: 7
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
>         at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Runnable.run(Runnable.java:17)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>       LOG from device Marvin: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>       LOG from device Marvin: HMR: Checking for updates to the bundle with hmr hash c0e7af62393125eaf0d7.
>       LOG from device Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/login/login.component.html
>       LOG from device Marvin: HMR: Successfully applied update with hmr hash c0e7af62393125eaf0d7. App is up to date.
>       LOG from device Marvin: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>       LOG from device Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/app.component.html
>       LOG from device Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/app.module.ts
>       LOG from device Marvin: HMR: The following modules were updated:
>       LOG from device Marvin: HMR:          ↻ ./app/app.component.ts
>       LOG from device Marvin: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>       Calling js method run failed
>       Error: Failed to create View with entry.create() function.
>
> ```
> StackTrace:
>   Frame: function:'ZoneAwareError', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
> ```
>
> line: 1298, column: 31
>         Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/builder/builder.js',
>   line: 45, column: 13
>         Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.setActivityContent',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 985, column: 32
>         Frame: function:'ActivityCallbacksImplementation.resetActivityContent',
>   file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/ui/frame/frame.js',
>   line: 946, column: 10
>         Frame: function:'_resetRootView', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/application/application.js',
>   line: 125, column: 13
>         Frame: function:'NativeScriptPlatformRef._livesync', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js',
>   line: 268, column: 19
>         Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/platform-common.js',
>   line: 97, column: 80
>         Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invokeTask', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 421, column: 23
>         Frame: function:'Zone.runTask', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 188, column: 39
>         Frame: function:'ZoneTask.invokeTask', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 496, column: 28
>         Frame: function:'ZoneTask.invoke', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 485, column: 40
>         Frame: function:'timer', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 1561, column: 23
>         Frame: function:'invoke', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.js',
>   line: 19, column: 45
>         Frame: function:'ZoneDelegate.invoke', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 388, column: 18
>         Frame: function:'Zone.runGuarded', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 151, column: 39
>         Frame: function:'', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/zone-js/dist/zone-nativescript.js',
>   line: 129, column: 23
>         Frame: function:'run', file:'file:///data/data/org.nativescript.preview/files/app/tns_modules/tns-core-modules/timer/timer.js',
>   line: 23, column: 7
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
>         at com.tns.gen.java.lang.Runnable.run(Runnable.java:17)
>         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>       LOG from device Marvin: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
>       LOG from device Marvin: An uncaught Exception occurred on "main" thread.
>       Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}:
>   com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
>       Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
>
> ```
> StackTrace:
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.nativescript.preview/com.tns.NativeScriptActivity}:
> ```
>
> com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
>       Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3172)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
>         at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1906)
>         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6863)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>         at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:537)
>         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
>       Caused by: com.tns.NativeScriptException: Calling js method onCreate failed
>       Error: Main entry is missing. App cannot be started. Verify app bootstrap.
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodNative(Native Method)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.dispatchCallJSMethodNative(Runtime.java:1242)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethodImpl(Runtime.java:1122)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1109)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1089)
>         at com.tns.Runtime.callJSMethod(Runtime.java:1081)
>         at com.tns.NativeScriptActivity.onCreate(NativeScriptActivity.java:20)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7149)
>         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7140)
>         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1288)
>         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3017)
>         ... 11 more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add **enableProdMode()** in **main.ts** file in the project.

**Like:-**

```
import { platformNativeScriptDynamic } from "nativescript-angular/platform";
import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import { enableProdMode } from "@angular/core";

enableProdMode();
platformNativeScriptDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

**app.component.ts:-**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "ns-app",
  templateUrl: "app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

**login.component.ts:-**

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "ns-login",
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html"
})
export class LoginComponent { }
```